# Cubic made Custom ISO (initramfs) unable to find medium containing a live file system

Tags: 18.04, initramfs, custom-distributions

After creating custom Ubuntu 18.04 ISO through Cubic app. Completion is happening without any error.

But while trying to use the same media to install the same in my production VM (on OVM), facing the said issue.

" (initramfs) unable to find medium containing a live file system "

Comment: Is the ISO mounted correctly on your VM enviroment? It could be that the ISO gets unmounted soon after booting so the installer cannot find the medium.